# Golang: Values containing the types defined in this package should not be copied

Tags: go, synchronization, mutex

The link https://golang.org/pkg/sync/ states "Values containing the types defined in this package should not be copied."

Why is it so? What would happen if I ignore the advice ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would simply not work as a synchronization primitive anymore. At best you would get unpredictable behavior.
Think of a lock (for instance) as a flag. If it is locked, the flag is set. If you copy that lock (you copy the flag's state), the copy would behave as if it was locked while it’s not. If you unlock the copy, the original won’t change so it will behave as if it was locked while it’s not supposed to be locked anymore.